# Проблема отправки голосового сообщения в ВК, используя vk_api и requests

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, requests

Вот код:

```
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType
import vk_api
from urllib.request import urlretrieve, urlopen
from gtts import gTTS 
import requests
import json
import tempfile
import subprocess



vk = vk_api.VkApi(token="токен группы")
vk._auth_token()
longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk, 185856063)
vk = vk.get_api()

vk2 = vk_api.VkApi(token='токен человека')
vk2._auth_token()
vk2 = vk2.get_api()
while True:
    for event in longpoll.listen():
        if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
            if event.object.peer_id != event.object.from_id:
                print(event,'\n')
                if event.object.text.lower() == "тест":
                    text2 = 'lol'
                    tts = gTTS(text=text2, lang='en')
                    name = "say.ogg"
                    tts.save(name)
                    audio = open('say.ogg','rb')

                    a=vk2.docs.getMessagesUploadServer(type='audio_message')

                    print(a,'\n')
                    b = requests.post(a['upload_url'], files={'file':audio}).json()

                    print(b,'\n')
                    c = vk2.docs.save(file=b['file'])

                    docum = 'doc%s_%s_%s'%(c['audio_message']['owner_id'],c['audio_message']['id'],c['audio_message']['access_key'])
                    print(docum,'\n')
                    vk2.messages.send(peer_id = (event.object.peer_id),random_id = (0),attachment='doc483977513_529842114_f37d87b7102d22013c',message='LOL')
                    requests.post('https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send',data={'peer_id':event.object.peer_id,'attachment':'doc483977513_529842114_f37d87b7102d22013c','random_id':0,'access_token':'токен','v':'5.64'})
```

**P.S. Последние две строки считаю равнозначными!**

Так вот, в любом из методов отправки сообщения (через библиотеку vk_api, и через метод POST), если использовать их от токена группы, отправляется пустое сообщение или (на смартфоне) '*(контент удален)*'.
Строка кода:

```
requests.post('https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send',data={'peer_id':event.object.peer_id,'attachment':'doc483977513_529842114_f37d87b7102d22013c','random_id':0,'access_token':'токен','v':'5.64'})
```

[image: Ошибка при отправке через группу]

Всё бы ничего, но при отправке через пользователя - всё отправляется без проблем!
Строка кода:

```
vk2.messages.send(peer_id = (event.object.peer_id),random_id = (0),attachment='doc483977513_529842114_f37d87b7102d22013c',message='LOL')
```

[image: Отправленное голосовое сообщение]

**Меняя токены, во всех случаях пользователь отправляет ГС, а группа пустоту!**

Answer (score 0):

Советую использовать внутренние методы vk_api ваш код имеет сложные ненужные строки я сейчас как раз занимаюсь разработкой бота не используйте библиотеку request гораздо удобнее Например чтобы отправить сообщение просто сформируйте словарь:

```
def write_aud_msg_chat(chat_id, attachment):
    return vk.method('messages.send', {'chat_id': chat_id, 'attachment': attachment, 'random_id': 0})
```

мне непонятно зачем загружать сообщение на сервер если просто можно заранее загрузить в документы группы сообщение и просто его прикреплять. Так же авторизацию можно выполнить так:

```
vk = vk_api.VkApi(token=token)
group = '123456789'
wait = 25
longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk, group, wait)
for event in longpoll.listen():
```

Если же вы хотите авторизоваться с помощью пользователя просто укажите его токен (чтобы его получить перейдите по ссылке и скопируйте из адресной строки то что после acces_token= и до &: https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=2685278&scope=1073737727&redirect_uri=https://api.vk.com/blank.html&display=page&response_type=token&revoke=1 ):

```
vk1 = vk_api.VkApi(token=token1)
```

Не используйте цикл While он только нагружает систему
Так же я думаю вот эти переменные вам помогут пишите их сразу как сработал MESSAGE_NEW:

```
    peer_id = event.object.peer_id
    chat_id = peer_id - 2000000000
    user = event.object.from_id
    mess = event.object.text.lower()
```

Comment: "_мне непонятно зачем загружать сообщение на сервер если просто можно заранее загрузить в документы группы сообщение и просто его прикреплять_" - файл каждый раз меняется, так как там создание голосового сообщения библиотекой gTTS.

Comment: спасибо, что вы помогли улучшить код, но это не решает мою проблему)